QField packaging step fails: it scans all file system unncecessarily
I'm using QField 4.9.1 on QGIS 3-38 Grenoble, on Ubuntu 22 and 24; whenever I try to package my project it takes around two minutes and yields the error:

Forbidden characters in filesystem path(s) ""Descargas/f_entrega_frutos_semillas_a_resem:OLD.xlsx", ".local/share/gvfs-metadata/admin:-014c46e6.log", ".local/share/gvfs-metadata/admin:", ".local/share/containers/storage/overlay/3306b151:"...

The end of the message says it's looking for characters such as ":", "|", "<", etc., but it does this for every file in my system apparently, not just the files in the project, I even tried with a single gpkg and it still scans all the file system.
How can I solve this issue? There are a lot of files listed in the error message and maybe some are important for another app, so deleting each will be cumbersome and risky.

Well I did manage to change file names or delete all those files with ":", "<", "=", etc., and I could pack the project for Qfield, although it also wanted to copy all directories to the package, and I had to manually uncheck several directories that stayed with the checkmark

The plugin will scan for files in all the directories below the QGIS project file (.qgz), so if there are no directories below the .qgz it won't take too long scanning.
